# Read multiple files in a directory and compare with another file

Tags: linux, perl, unix, operating-system

I have two files

```
File 1 in reading directory is of following format 

Read 1 A T
Read 3 T C
Read 5 G T
Read 7 A G
Read 10 A G
Read 12 C G

File 2 in directory contains

    Read 5 A G
    Read 6 T C
    Read 7 G A
    Read 8 G A
    Read 20 A T
```

File2 contains

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

I need to read file 2 first for positons and print out the corresponding value from opened file in directory in horizontal manner. If no match for that postion, it is printed as "-". The output for above should be

```
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Read T - C - T - G
Read - - - - G C A
```

I need to do that for all the files and print in above format in another row. so output will be only one file with number of rows equals no of files. Can i do this in perl easily?

Comment: This should like homework - please show what you have tried and people are more likely to help you

Comment: This is by means no home work. I am new to bioinformatics and trying to learn the language here at work place. i am not looking for entire solution either. I just need a direction. I am reading second file with positions first and then opening directory and opening the files one by one and pushing contents to array. then after that i am not sure how to compare positions with opened files. Also how to print them horizontally ?

Comment: You have three input files, two of which you call "File2". It is not obvious how the inputs map to the desired output. For example, why does column 1 contain "- T" (or do I even read it correctly)? Does (the first) File2 always override input from File1, like it appears to in column 5 in the output? Please edit your question.

Comment: (Oops, I mean vice versa for the column 5 observation.)

Answer (score 0):

If the files size is small you could read them into memory:

```
#read input files
use IO::File;
my $file1_data;
open(my $file1_fh,"<","/path/file1.data") or die $!;
#read file1
while(my $line=<$file1_fh>){
  chomp($line);
  my ($read,$pos,$col1,$col2) = split(/ /,$line);
  $file1_data->{$pos} = [$col1,$col2];
}
#read file2
my $file2_data;
open(my $file2_fh,"<","/path/file2.data") or die $!;
while(my $line=<$file2_fh>){
  chomp($line);
  my ($read,$pos,$col1,$col2) = split(/ /,$line);
  $file2_data->{$pos} = [$col1,$col2];
}
#read pos file
my @positions;
while(my $pos=<$posfile_fh>){
  chomp($pos);  
  push(@positions,$pos)
}
foreach my $pos (@positions){
    print "$pos\t";
}
print "\n";
foreach my $pos (@positions){
    my $data = defined $file1_data->{$pos}->[0]?$file1_data->{$pos}->[0]:"-";
    print "$pos\t$data"
}
print "\n";
foreach my $pos (@positions){
    my $data = defined $file2_data->{$pos}->[0]?$file2_data->{$pos}->[0]:"-";
    print "$pos\t$data"
}
print "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you're using the second data column only. Here's a simple perl program to do that, if there are any questions, feel free to ask. I used a third input file and it's possible to use as many files as you want. I changed the format to include `42` at the end.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

# try to open format file
my $ffn = shift @ARGV or die "you didn't provide a format file name!\n";
open my $ffh, '<', $ffn;

# read format file
my @format = <$ffh>;
close $ffh;
chomp for @format; # get rid of newlines

# prepare output
print '     ' . join(' ' => @format) . "\n";

# iterate over all .txt files in the data directory
foreach my $data_fn (<data/*.txt>) {

    # iterate over all lines of the data file
    open my $data_fh, '<', $data_fn;
    my %data = ();
    foreach my $line (<$data_fh>) {

        # parse input lines (only)
        next unless $line =~ /Read (\d+) ([ACGT]) ([ACGT])/;
        my ($pos, $first, $second) = ($1, $2, $3);

        # store data
        $data{$pos} = $second;
    }

    # print summary
    print 'Read ' . join(' ' => map {$data{$_} // '-'} @format) . "\n";
}
```

The output:

```
$ perl bio.pl format.txt
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 42
Read T - C - T - G -
Read - - - - G C A -
Read - C - T - - - A
```

HTH! :)